# Same scale for twinx() combo plot with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Let's use the classic example of weekly precipitation:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from random import randint

data = {
    'Week': [i for i in range(1,9)],
    'Weekly Precipitation': [randint(1,10) for i in range(1,9)]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Let's also add a column with the cumulative precipitation:

```py
df['Cumulative'] = df['Weekly Precipitation'].expanding(min_periods=2).sum()
```

Now, let's say I want a single chart with a barplot for the weekly precipitation, and a lineplot with the cumulative precipitation. So I do this:

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
sns.barplot(x='Week', y='Weekly Precipitation', data=df, ax=ax1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x='Week', y='Cumulative', data=df, ax=ax2)
```

Which yields this plot:

[image]

And you can see the problem: while both series are commensurate, both x axes use a different scale, which  distorts the visualization, as the line should always be higher than the bars.

So, instead of twin axes, I'm trying to put both plot on the same axis:

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax1.set_facecolor('white')
sns.barplot(x='Week', y='Weekly Precipitation', data=df, ax=ax1)
sns.lineplot(x='Week', y='Cumulative', data=df, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_ylabel('Precipitation')
```

Now, of course, the scale is right (although I have to do with a single y label), but... the second plot is shifted to the right by one tick!

[image]

How does that even make sense?!

Comment: try this:`ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(ax2.get_yticks()[0], ax2.get_yticks()[-1], len(ax1.get_yticks())))`

Comment: Thanks, that  almost works. However, it seems that my line plot is shifted to the right by one tick, and the the y ticks are not exactly flush: https://i.imgur.com/HUfjcM7.png

Comment: That's right. I tried everything and it didn't improve, so I made a comment. If you edit the question as it is now, someone else may be able to answer it.

Comment: I tried the code once more now. I created it through trial and error, so I cannot explain the rationale behind it. `ax2.set_ylim(0, df['Cumulative'].max());ax2.grid(True);import matplotlib.ticker;nticks = 8;ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.LinearLocator(nticks));ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.LinearLocator(nticks))`

Comment: I'm not sure why it shifts, but it goes away when you set it to the numerical X axis. `xx = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];sns.barplot(x=xx,...);sns.lineplot(x=xx,...)`

Comment: lineplots use a numeric x-axis, while barplots always use categorical x-axis.   You can change both plots to use categorical axes e.g. by setting `x = [str(i) for i in x]`

Comment: Yes, that's it: `sns.lineplot(x=[str(i) for i in df['Week']], y='Cumulative', data=df, ax=ax1)` Thanks for the explanation!